# JavaFx SQLite driver is not suitable

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, maven, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a SQLite database on my local device (Ubuntu).
my setup is VS Code with Maven

#### The error

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/home/idir/embag/chek/Data/Checks.sql

#### Database.java, connect method

```
public void Connect() {
    String AbsolutePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    path = "jdbc:sqlite:"+ AbsolutePath + DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME ;        
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(path);
        if (conn != null){
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("A new database has been created.");
        }    
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

#### Maven pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.36.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Module-info.java

```
requires java.sql;
requires mysql.connector.java;
```

#### What I tried

- +3 hours of search with no hope

Comment: You are using the wrong JDBC driver; you are using a driver for MySQL, but it looks like the database you are using is SQLite. Use the driver for SQLite, which you can find here: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: thanks for the response that really helped pointing me in the right path .

Answer (score 1):

## Don’t mix database engines

You are asking your MySQL driver to make a connection using a string meant for SQLite.

MySQL and SQLite are two entirely separate different database engines. So your code makes no sense.

---

By the way…

In modern Java, there is no need to call `Class.forName`. JDBC drivers are now automatically loaded via the [Java SPI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) facility.

Generally best to separate your code for configuring the database connection info from the code that accesses the database. Have the first produce a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object that is passed into the second.

Comment: thanks for the response much appreciated . Indeed that was a grave mistake on my part , still i fixed it by removing the mysql you pointed to . and add this line to the module file  :   requires org.xerial.sqlitejdbc;

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by removing the MySQL dependency as pointed out by the previous responses .

Added to the `Module-info.java`:

```
requires org.xerial.sqlitejdbc;
```

Also added this to `pom.xml`:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver</resource>
</transformer>
```

Comment: That last part is only necessary if you create a fat JAR (shaded JAR).